# Codeception, как в собственном хелпере подключиться к 2-м БД?

Tags: php, phpstorm, codeception

Пишу свой хелпер в котором хочу реализовать функции для последующего их вызова в тестах.
В к кон фиге codeception.yml:

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    enabled:
        - Db
        - PhpBrowser
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=rfm_db'
            user: 'test_user'
            password: 'passwd'
            databases:
        Db2:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=rfm_db_online_store'
            user: 'test_user'
            password: 'passwd'
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://api.localhost/'
```

Вот код класса:

```
<?php

namespace Helper;


use Codeception\Module;

class Universal extends Module
{
    private $db1;
    private $db2;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $container = \Codeception\Util\Stub::make('Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer');
        $this->db1 = new Module\Db($container, $this->_getConfig('Db'));
        $this->db1->_getDbh();
        $this->db1->_initialize();
        $this->db2 = new Module\Db($container, $this->_getConfig('db2'));
        $this->db2->_getDbh();
        $this->db2->_initialize();
    }
}
```

При запуске codecept build:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: default in /home/shishmish/Work/gc/vendor/codeception/module-db/src/Codeception/Module/Db.php on line 351
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: dsn in /home/shishmish/Work/gc/vendor/codeception/module-db/src/Codeception/Module/Db.php on line 552
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: user in /home/shishmish/Work/gc/vendor/codeception/module-db/src/Codeception/Module/Db.php on line 552
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/shishmish/Work/gc/vendor/codeception/module-db/src/Codeception/Module/Db.php on line 552

In Db.php line 560:

  Db: invalid data source name while creating PDO connection
```

Хочу иметь возможность подключаться к 1-й и 2-й БД по необходимости

Comment: `Db2` != `db2`, судя по всему.

Comment: С регистром поигрался и в yml файле и вообще, не роляет